# Proxy or transform a Google Cast to a DLNA (DMS) to view on Oculus Go or other devices?

Tags: google-cast, dlna, oculusgo

I'm trying to cast a Google Chrome Tab on my Oculus Go device. However, every Oculus app I can find only supports DLNA (or some also do SMB). So I'm wondering if is there any proxy or transformer that can present a DLNA video source, like a webcam, to the Oculus and then connect that to the Google Chrome Tab casting in the background?